# Regular Expression - 4 digits in a row, but can't be all zeros

Tags: regex

I am looking for a solution that can exclusively be done with a regular expression.  I know this would be easy with variables, substrings, etc.

And I am looking for PCRE style regex syntax even though I mention vim.

I need to identify strings with 4 numeric digits, and they can't be all 0's.  So the following strings would be a match:

```
0001 
1000 
1234 
0101
```

And this would not:

```
0000
```

This is a substring that will occur at a set location within a large string, if that matters; I don't think it should. For example

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx0001xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx1000xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx1234xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx0101xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx0101xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxx0000xxxxx
```

Comment: cant you use substr like if ((substr(8,4)*1) > 0 ) then ok

Comment: oh wow. I was about to add in the near exact thing you were and then you beat me to it by a minute. I rolled back to your edit

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
 (?<!\d)(?!0000)\d{4}(?!\d)
```

or, more kindly/maintainably/sanely:

```
m{
     (?<! \d   )    # current point cannot follow a digit
     (?!  0000 )    # current point must not precede "0000"
     \d{4}          # match four digits at this point, provided...
     (?!  \d   )    # that they are not then followed by another digit
}x
```

Comment: Note to readers: If the question is not asking to exclude substrings of a longer numerical string, then the answer will be just `(?!0000)\d{4}` (or `(?!0{4})\d{4}`).

Comment: now show me how to do this in VIM!  very magic flag is acceptable

Answer (score 7):

Since I complained that the some of the answers here weren't regular expressions, I thought I'd best give you a regex answer.  This is primitive, there's probably a better way, but it does work:

```
([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][1-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9])
```

This checks for something which contains 0-9 in each location, except one which must lie in 1-9, preventing 0000 from matching.  You can probably write this simpler using \d instead of [0-9] if your regex parser supports that metacharacter.

Comment: Thank you @Richard, it may be primitive but it works :)

Answer (score 4):

Just match for 4 digits (`\d{4}` should do it) and then verify that your match is not equal to `'0000'`.

Comment: not writing a script - no variables - i am using grep and vim

Answer (score 4):

Since PCRE supports [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), `\d{4}(?<!0000)` will find any instance of four consecutive non-zero characters. See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?2tvik).

If you must make sure the match only occurs in the correct position of the string, you can use `^.{X}\d{4}(?<!0000).{Y}$` instead, where `X` and `Y` are the number of preceding and following characters, respectively (12 and 5 in your example.)

Comment: In general, using lookahead (as in tchrist's answer) is preferable than using lookbehind.

Comment: Right. Performance. And also, lookbehind may have limitations (or is not even implemented at all) in some regex engines.

Comment: @sawa: tchrist's answer *does* use a negative lookbehind.

Answer (score -2):

Test for a sequence of 3 digits (0-9), then a 4th with only (1-9)

```
/\d{3}[1-9]/
```

Comment: 1000 is an acceptable solution, 0000 is forbidden, your solution will reject 1000