# Need a regular expression - disallow all zeros

Tags: regex

I want to validate a string to meet the following conditions:

- Must be 6 characters long
- Only the first character can be alpha-numeric the rest must be numeric
- If first digit is alpha, it must be caps
- Can't be all zeros

I have the following regular expression that gets everything except the all zeros part.  Is there a way to disallow all zeros?

`^[A-Z0-9][0-9]{5}$`

Is the only way to do this to check the regex (and allow "000000") but then check specifically that it's not "000000"?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe something in here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311842/regular-expression-4-digits-in-a-row-but-cant-be-all-zeros

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just have a negative lookahead like this to disallow all 0s:

```
/^(?!0{6})[A-Z0-9][0-9]{5}$/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `(?!0+$)` negative lookahead to avoid matching a string that only contains 1 or more zeros:

```
/^(?!0+$)[A-Z0-9][0-9]{5}$/
  ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dcf5tq/1). This approach lets you just copy/paste the lookahead after `^` and not worry about how many chars the consuming part matches.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!0+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 1 or more `0` chars up to the end of the string (`$`)
- `[A-Z0-9]` - an uppercase ASCII letter or a digit
- `[0-9]{5}` - five digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I would do two passes. One with your first regex, and one with a new regex looking for all zeros.

Answer (score 1):

What if you checked for the all zeros case first and then, after determining that it's no all zeros apply your regex?

```
if ( NOT ALL ZEROS)
    APPLY REGEX
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it. It checks for not 000000 and your original regex.

```
(?!0{6})^[A-Z0-9][0-9]{5}$
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?!000000)[A-Z0-9][0-9]{5}` if lookahead is okay.

Answer (score 0):

This is Correct Answer Of this Regex

[O]{1}((?!0+$)[0-9]{1,5})

If you are work with specific Ids. so you must use that

Ex. 1. O0 -- Reject
    2. O00 -- Reject
    3. O00000 -- Reject
    4. O1 -- Success
    5. O01 -- success