# Regex for alpha numeric string - not all zeros

Tags: regex

Regex for an alpha numeric string which should not be all zeros, but can contain zero in first place

I have tried this regex

```
^(?![0]{1,40})[A-Z0-9]{1,40}$
```

but it is not allowing zero in first place. How can I allow for that?

Comment: I don't want any java script solutions. I just want a proper regex. And it is not mandatory that the string is strictly alphanumeric.

Comment: Can you show us examples of passing and failing numbers?

Comment: The definition is confusing.. what exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: Maybe you forgot about `$` in the lookahead? `^(?!0{1,40}$)[A-Z0-9]{1,40}$`. Or `^(?!0+$)[A-Z0-9]{1,40}$`

Comment: Thanks for the regex Wiktor Stribizew. It solved my problem....

Comment: If the string does not have to be "strictly" alphanumeric, what are the *precise* constraints?

Comment: I posted the correct answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609583/need-a-regular-expression-disallow-all-zeros/46641117#46641117.