# How to reject String "0" zero in Java with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have problem creating regex pattern to reject "0" value in String.
I have tried to negate the string as follows

```
[^!(?0)]
```

but i believe this is wrong. Because it will also reject the String that contain zero, such as 
10000". Is it possible to handle this with regex only? Because using if-else is easier though.

example:

- "0" - invalid
- "0000" - invalid
- "10" - valid
- "10000" - valid

Comment: You cannot use groups inside character classes. You can only list characters inside `[]`.

Comment: Try `^(?!0+$)\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/wwqYkE/1 In java `String regex = "^(?!0+$)\\d+$";`

Comment: Try `^(?!0).*` pattern

Comment: the one that I checked is partially right. But the one that I'm looking for is this answer from @Thefourthbird . Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i think the link that you claimed is different with my question. if I ask "how to match only the string that doesn't contain zero", then it will be a duplicate question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no it is different. I gave the example though. if i follow that pattern, then 10000 will be invalid too because it contains zero. in my case 00100, 1000, 1000000000 is valid input.

Comment: So, this is a dupe of another question. Changed to [Need a regular expression - disallow all zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609583/need-a-regular-expression-disallow-all-zeros). This topic is also covered very well on SO. Also, see [Regex: match everything but specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-specific-pattern) to learn the ways to reject strings that match a generic pattern with exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
^0+$
```

... and validate *against* it.

Essentially, it checks the input from start to end to make sure it's only made of 0s. 
You only need to invert the validation.

Or better:

```
!myString.matches("0+")
```

`String#matches` matches the whole string against a pattern. Negating the result of the invocation ensures only `0+` occurrences filling the whole string are invalid.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if string *doesn't start* from `0` (i.e. `"01"`, `"010"` and `"00100"` are all *invalid* strings), you can try

```
^(?!0).*
```

pattern, where

```
^     - (anchor) start of the string
(?!0) - negative look behind (not start from 0)
.*    - any symbols
```

or (without regular expressions)

```
bool result = !myString.startsWith("0");
```