# Regular expression to look for a numeric range between two numbers

Tags: regex

I'm setting up some rules on an email filtering appliance and it will only accept regular expressions to define numeric ranges. Unfortunately I know absolutely nothing about regular expressions. I need to flag values between a certain range. for example I need to start at value 1000001 and end at value 8000000 I have partially done this with this command [Kudos to this gentleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311842/regular-expression-4-digits-in-a-row-but-cant-be-all-zeros)

```
(?<!\d)(?!1000000)\d{7}(?!\d)
```

This works great, except it flags 7 digit values 1000001 and above. How can I set a limit on this? Or would I need to write a completely new expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change `\d{7}` to `[1-7]\d{6}` that would ensure that the first digit found as a part of the number is within the range 1-7 (and as a bonus, eliminates the possibility of leading zeroes mucking things up).

```
(?<!\d)(?!1000000)[1-7]\d{6}(?!\d)
```

This will make the highest accepted value 7999999.  If it should be inclusive of the endpoint 8000000, you could add it explicitly, something like:

```
(?<!\d)(?!1000000)([1-7]\d{6}|8000000)(?!\d)
```