# Regex for integers 7-12 digits long

Tags: regex

I have another question today. I have an email appliance that I am setting up to filter certain data, but it can only do this via regular expression. I have this partially accomplished [thanks to this fine gentleman.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902754/regular-expression-to-look-for-a-numeric-range-between-two-numbers) What I need to accomplish now is something a bit more complex. I should add that I am a complete novice at regex. Right now i'm using this:

```
(?<!\d)(?!1000000)([1-7]\d{6}|8000000)(?!\d)
```

To find 7 digit integers within a range from 1000001 to 8000000, what i'm looking to do now is find integers between 1000000 and 12000000000, I can re purpose this code by simply changing up the section here

```
([1-7]\d{6}
```

But from my understanding this would require I format 5 separate expressions to find the data I need (I may be completely off base about this, but I don't know enough about regex to change this line to what I need). I would prefer one expression to look for data between 7-12 digits and stop at certain explicit 12 digit value. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "between 1000000 and 12000000000" did you mean to include the endpoints?

Comment: All i'm looking to do is start at 1000000 or 1000001 and end at 12000000000, if 1000000 matches, and/or if 12000000000 matches it doesn't matter, as the extra matches aren't going to throw off what i'm doing

Comment: Then you can drop that initial negative lookahead in your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dust having settled, here is what I believe is the simplest "acceptable" range in question, with @hvd's caveats about use of `\d`:

```
\b([1-9]\d{6,9}|1[01]\d{9})\b
```

This includes 1000000 and excludes 12000000000 for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: This allows `00000000`, does it not?

Comment: Updated and undeleted. :-)

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. Removes some unnecessary complexity

Comment: If simplicity is the goal (and it should be), use word boundary (`\b`) instead of lookaround.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the feedback.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

1000000 to 12000000000 (exclusive) can be almost:

1000000 to 9999999: `[1-9][0-9]{6}`

10000000 to 99999999: `[1-9][0-9]{7}`

100000000 to 999999999: `[1-9][0-9]{8}`

1000000000 to 9999999999: `[1-9][0-9]{9}`

10000000000 to 11999999999: `1[01][0-9]{9}`

Some regex syntax variants allow `a{m,n}` to get `a` anywhere from `m` to `n` times, allowing the first four of these to be combined to one. The full regex for a complete match would look like

`[1-9][0-9]{6,9}|1[01][0-9]{9}`

which you can then wrap in `(?<![0-9])(...)(?![0-9])` to allow searching parts of strings.

This also matches `1000000`, so to exclude that, you can use the same `(?!...)` construct you've already got, except modified to still allow `1000000` followed by other digits.

`(?<![0-9])((?!1000000(?![0-9]))[1-9][0-9]{6,9}|1[01][0-9]{9})(?![0-9])`

By the way, I'm using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` because I don't know which regex dialect you're using. `\d` also matches other digits than our 0123456789 in some dialects.

Comment: Hat's off to you. I'm going to delete mine now. I learned something and you clearly have this well in hand! :-)

Comment: Could you simply this by adding a `$` at the end of `(?!1000000$)`?

Comment: This would work, But i prefer the idea of modifying my original statement. I did try this approach and it works just fine however.

Comment: Heh, thanks :) The `(?![0-9])` instead of `$` is because the question asks for numbers as substrings in a larger string, to `1000000x` should be rejected.

Comment: @user2796751 Ah, that's fair enough. I don't think the answer you accepted gives you the results you're asking for, though.

Comment: Except for the `$` problem you mentioned. What else do you see?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin It also allows `12000000000`.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. if 12000000000 matches its not a problem, the extra match wont make a difference one way or another.

Comment: Then you have a more complicated regex than you need. Do any other numbers not matter? ;-) Anyway, suggest you +1 @hvd for being first, accurate and robust. :-)

Comment: @PeterAlfvin When you say its more complicated then necessary, what do you mean?

Comment: I meant that excluding the lower bound requires extra complexity (i.e. the negative lookahead), and that's part of the accepted answer. Similarly, including the upper bound requires extra complexity as well. You said you originally had 1000001 as the lower end of your range, but now wanted 1000000 as the lower end, which is what hvd (and I) gave you. Then you said you didn't want the endpoints, which makes the lower bound the same as you had originally, which raises the question of why you asked for something different. Anyway, as I said, I thought @hvd (who I just encountered) was responsive.

Comment: Sorry if i'm being confusing about this, I tried be as straightforward as possible, all i'm looking to do is start at 1000000 or 1000001 and end at 12000000000, if 1000000 matches, and/or if 12000000000 matches it doesn't matter, as the extra matches aren't going to throw off what i'm doing.

Comment: @hvd +1, for what it's worth ... getting the accept for myself was not my intent. ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlfvin You managed to figure out what the OP wanted, as opposed to what the OP asked for, so it's only right that your answer is accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but isn't it just

```
^[1-9][0-9]{6,11}$
```

Comment: That includes numbers greater than 1.2*10**9

Comment: I think the number in the question was 1.2E10.

Comment: Whatever it is ;-) your regex still allows the first digit to 2 or more, which means it doesn't "stop" at 120000...

Answer (score 0):

```
^([1-9][0-9]{6,9}|1[0-2][0-9]{9})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/r/8fSpTOD8NI8tlnU5)